# Is there a difference between [formal-semantics] and [language-lawyer]?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

Currently [formal-semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formal-semantics) seems to be about 20% questions about the rigorous mathematical sense of semantics, and 80% questions about a specific language where the asker is concerned with correctly interpreting the language specification or reference.

I'm tempted to manually retag the second category with [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), but I'm not sure.

The tag wiki starts out pretty clear:

> In programming language theory, semantics is the field concerned with the rigorous mathematical study of the meaning of programming languages.

Okay, sure, "mathematical" might not be the right word for whether copying an unintialized pointer counts as "access" for the purpose of alias analysis, but the second sentence elaborates:

> It does so by evaluating the **meaning of syntactically legal strings defined by a specific programming language, showing the computation** involved.

The C spec definitely defines what it means for code to be **syntactically legal**, and also **defines meaning** in terms of **computation** performed by the abstract machine. Are questions about the interpretation of the C standard on-topic? (There is no such question in the tag now.) Is [a question about method resolution in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)? Is [a formal introduction to Bash as a programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207168/a-semantics-for-bash-scripts)? [Block scope in ECMAScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6)? These are the highest voted questions in the tag.

Should the tag wiki be edited to exclude such questions, and the existing ones retagged / untagged? Or does usage dominate: should we accept that [formal-semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formal-semantics) *is* applicable to questions such as the above, and make it a synonym for [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) (or some other tag that's even better)?

Comment: What benefits would accrue from teasing out the specific intricacies of these two tags, if any?

Comment: That's just what I'd like to know. If the answer is "none", that seems like a clear indication that the tags are in fact synonyms.

Comment: Concretely, I'd like to find that Rust question under [tag:language-lawyer] when I search for it in a few years after having forgotten the details.

Comment: `that seems like a clear indication that the tags are in fact synonyms` -- is a non-sequitur.

Comment: But is it a normative or non-normative non sequitur?

Comment: If we had more formal semantics we'd need fewer language lawyers. The C standard is not an example of formal semantics, it is an example of informal semantics. Since the teaching & understanding of semantics in software culture is atrocious, it's understandable that someone would think that explicitly dealing with semantics is being "formal". It's lucky when someone even understands the notion of "semantics".

Comment: @RobertHarvey the people who can answer (when tagged correctly) [tag:formal-semantics] questions are a completely different and smaller group than those who can answer [tag:language-lawyer] questions.

Comment: Perhaps another good way to tell the differences is that [tag:formal-semanics] would on-topic for [computerscience.SE], but [tag:language-lawyer] certainly wouldn't.

Comment: @philipxy: That viewpoint is embraced by folks who think that the world is an orderly place, and that everything can be described logically.  I abandoned that belief years ago.

Comment: @RobertHarvey A programming language is an artificial "world", and is already a formal notation, and certainly can be usefully formally--precisely & completely--defined. (I'm done.)

Comment: Can't believe I've been around this long and had never come across the language-lawyer tag. Seems kind of bizarre that we have a tag named like that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When I first posted this question I thought the tags were basically synonymous, but after thinking about it some I've changed my mind. [formal-semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formal-semantics) is related to [formal-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formal-methods) and [formal-verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formal-verification), not language lawyering. The tag wiki is clear enough already and the volume of mistagged questions is low enough to do by hand.

Remove [formal-semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formal-semantics) from the questions that don't relate to mathematical formalism, and selectively retag a fraction of those with [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) (several questions fit neither tag). No further action is required.

Comment: And in those few languages that are specified using formal semantics, we might have questions where *both* tags apply :-)

Comment: After reading the question, I was about to post an answer saying the very same thing as your answer. My take is that formal-semantics is a child tag under formal methods, whereas language-lawyer is about reading language standards in formal ways, when a  practical use-case isn't necessarily present.

Comment: Works for me. No other answers have been posted or seem likely, so I'm planning to accept this one but I'll take a stab at cleaning up [tag:formal-semantics] now.